# How to change format from rows[[ to [ javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I got this format from Google bigquery, but I need to change this :

```
"Rows: [[{"insert_time":{"value":"2020-12-23T21:04:12.316Z"},"_id":null,"viewId":"106851427","userId":"9f84898d-7e13-4218-835a-6db82ade9931","AletName":"Conv between: video_screen - click_on_screen - true and camera - click - success_save_recording_settings","AletType":"Conversion has been change","date":{"value":"2020-12-05"},"Hour":"04","EventsConv":4,"ConvMedianHourly":0.3666666666666667,"Actual_VS_expected":"Got: 4 but expected: 0.37"},{"insert_time":{"value":"2020-12-23T21:04:12.316Z"},"_id":null,"viewId":"104831427","userId":"9f84898d-7e13-4218-835a-6db72ace9931","AletName":"Conv between: video - select - youtube and category - select - New - Karaoke","AletType":"Conversion has been change","date":{"value":"2020-12-05"},"Hour":"03","EventsConv":21,"ConvMedianHourly":3,"Actual_VS_expected":"Got: 21 but expected: 3"}]]
```

To this

```
"[{"viewId":"62437650","source":"Google},{"viewId":"6166150","source":"Google}]"
```

I tried to use

```
x.rows[0]
```

but it's don't work.

Comment: Please show the results of `console.log(x)`.

Comment: Hey Idan, can you provide a bit more context here: It will depend on how you have the return-data stored from BigQuery, since it will be different if you are receiving it as a string vs as an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I guess right and your query result is a string, then you can use :

```
let newX = x.substring(8,x.length-1);
```

//If you need an object:

```
JSON.parse(newX);
```

//If you don’t have a String but an object, you could do:

```
JSON.stringify(x)
```

//before

Answer (score 0):

You can use `x[0]` if you are okay with maintaining the other properties along with `viewId` and `source`.